# Google Captcha code plugin's parameters not available when in form enctype

Tags: html, security, jsp, servlets

I have used Google captcha code and it works well. The `form` has no enctype too. I wanted to upload images within the same `form` element. Then an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` was added to the form's attribute.  I faced the following problems and I use JSP servlets:

**1.**

```
String challenge = request.getParameter("recaptcha_challenge_field"); 

String uresponse = request.getParameter("recaptcha_response_field");
```

here challenge and uresponse gave null values and therefore

```
ReCaptchaResponse reCaptchaResponse = reCaptcha.checkAnswer(remote, challenge, uresponse);
```

gave null pointer exceptions.

**Edit** : I found it later that when `enctype="multipart/form-data`in `form` tag is used, parameters and its value cannot be retrieved as `request.getParameter('')` in Servlet.

**2.**  Then I tried to get values for above parameters (challenge and uresponse) through the `FileItem` as following

```
 FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
   ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
   List items = null;
   items = upload.parseRequest(request);
   Iterator itr = items.iterator();                        
                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
                        if (item.isFormField()) {
                            String name = item.getFieldName();
                            System.out.println("name: " + name);
                            String value = item.getString();
                            System.out.println("value: " + value); // closing scopes   ....
```

These outputs gave no print results for  'recaptcha_challenge_field' and 'recaptcha_response_field'. But other parameters and values of HTML `input` elements are available.  What I observed is, when the form enctype is removed, servlets can have those parameters ('recaptcha_challenge_field' and 'recaptcha_response_field') and its values. When only form enctype is added, parameters not available in servlets.(request.getParameter('recaptha challenge parameter or recaptha-response-field parameter')).

**Edit** I checked whether the browser sends those parameters(recaptha-challenge ane recaptha-response-field.) with their values and found that browser sends all parameters well. The problem might be in servlet and getting parameters and values inside the `FileItem`

I want to upload images with this Google captcha code (for human verifications). My current implementation does not work.  Does anyone let me know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in the html itself. When a `input` type-file is empty(user hasn't not select a file from the local pc),it is difficult or (cannot be done) to retrieve parameter names and their values (in servelt) of those all below html elements' names in my scenario as mentioned in my problem.